# Compatibility of Alternative Biometric Devices (e.g., ZKteco uFace800 plus) with Odoo 15 Module for Attendance Integration

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10, odoo-15, odoo-16

I want to integrate biometric attendance into Odoo 15. To achieve this, I have installed the "hr_zk_attendance" module, which is designed specifically for the ZKteco uFace202 or ZKteco iFace990 devices. However, I have been unable to find these devices in the market. Instead, I have come across alternative models such as the ZKteco uFace800 plus, which are readily available. My question is, will these alternative devices be compatible with the "hr_zk_attendance" module? If not, what modifications or customizations should I make to ensure compatibility with these devices?

Comment: That's probably a question you should ask the author of this module?

Answer (score 0):

Check the technical notes on [github](https://github.com/CybroOdoo/CybroAddons/tree/15.0/hr_zk_attendance#technical-notes)

> This integration is only applicable for the device ZKteco model 'uFace 202' & 'iFace990'